# Convert the sql query to LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq

Can anyone help me to convert this SQL query to LINQ

```
Select 
    ALL_VAL 
from  
    DDL_VALUES 
where 
    tbl_nm = 'RCond' 
    and P_key in (select max(cPk) 
                  from 
                      (select rule_src VAL_P, rule VAL_C 
                       from rdef 
                       where rule_key = 123
                       union
                       select rule VAL_P, rule_c VAL_C 
                       from rdef 
                       where rule_key = 123) AA,
                      (select a.ALL_VAL VAL_P, b.ALL_VAL VAL_C, B.ID_KEY cpk 
                       from DDL_VALUES a, DDL_VALUES b 
                       where a.id_key = B.P_KEY and a.ALL_VAL <> b.ALL_VAL) BB
                   where 
                       AA.VAL_P = BB.VAL_P and AA.VAL_C = BB.VAL_C)
```

Comment: can you give table and expected output ?

Comment: I am sorry... i don't have access to them... DDL_values, rdef are tables... 123 can be any value.  I tried many ways but unsuccessful...

Comment: Can anyone help me to covert the given SQL query into LinqQuery.. i deadly need it...

Comment: Finally I got the answer... by writing 2 LINQ queries